# Java Caching String.split Regex

Tags: java, regex

We can `split` a line by a regex like so:

```
String regex = "[\\p{P} ]+";
String[] split = line.split(regex);
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to cache the regex into a `Pattern`:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(regex);
```

Then `split` using the `Pattern`, something to this extent:

```
String[] split = line.split(PATTERN);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, not with [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), but with [`Pattern.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split(java.lang.CharSequence)) you can:

```
String[] parts = PATTERN.split(line);
```

> But I was wondering if there is a way to cache the regex into a Pattern:

What you really meant was, split by a *compiled regex* that can be reused.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
String[] split = PATTERN.split(line);
```

[Pattern javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split(java.lang.CharSequence))

Answer (score 1):

You can use: [Pattern#split(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split(java.lang.CharSequence)) method like this:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\p{P} ]+");
```

Then use it:

```
Strig[] arr = p.split(line);
```